# Banco de Dados para Enquete

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem

Estou fazendo um sistema de questionário e estou com dificuldades modelar a base de dados. Preciso que meu sistema seja "inteligente" a ponto de fazer perguntas diferentes de acordo com as respostas.

Por exemplo, minha primeira pergunta sempre será:

Você é um?

- Homem
- Mulher

Caso a resposta a pergunta ID 1 seja: Homem. Farei a pergunta ID 2:

Dos itens abaixo, por qual você mais se interessa?

- Esportes
- Video Games
- Viagens

Ao responder a pergunta ID 2 com Esportes, farei a pergunta ID 3.

Qual esporte?

- Futebol
- Corrida
- Luta

Agora voltando para a pergunta ID 1 em outro cenário. Caso a resposta seja Mulher. Farei a pergunta ID 2:

Dos itens abaixo, por qual você mais se interessa?

- Esportes
- Gastronomia
- Viagens
- Estética

Caso a resposta seja Viagens farei a pergunta ID 4

Qual destes destinos você gostaria de conhecer?

- Dubai
- China
- Paris

Perceba que tenho perguntas iguais com respostas diferentes. E a combinação de uma pergunta com uma resposta deve determinar qual será a próxima pergunta, ou seja, tenho perguntas que serão exibidas apenas em determinadas situações. E uma mesma pergunta pode conter respostas diferentes dependendo da resposta à pergunta anterior.

Comment: Você tem alguma coisa que já fez? Mostra aí. Essencialmente precisa ter uma ou mais colunas que determine(m) a dependência. Esta(s) coluna(s) precisa(s) indicar qual é a questão e a resposta que precisa ter sido respondida para aquela pergunta ser feita. É possível fazer isto nas respostas também, mas acho pouco provável que seja útil modificar as respostas possíveis, é mais fácil escolher só qual pergunta é condicional. Como você está fazendo. Se tiver situações mais complexas para determinar quais perguntas serão ativadas, aí complica bem e só com mais detalhes para responder.

Answer (score 2):

Alberto, apesar de duas perguntas terem exatamente o mesmo texto e do ponto de vista do usuário elas serem a mesma, a nivel de banco de dados elas não precisam ser a mesma pergunta.

[image: Schema Quiz]

Segue o script de criação das tabelas para o SQL-Server:

```
CREATE SCHEMA [quiz]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [quiz].[Pergunta]    Script Date: 1/13/2016 9:06:19 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [quiz].[Pergunta](
    [PerguntaID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Descricao] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Pergunta] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PerguntaID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [quiz].[Resposta]    Script Date: 1/13/2016 9:06:19 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [quiz].[Resposta](
    [RespostaID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PerguntaID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Descricao] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [PerguntaProximaID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Resposta] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RespostaID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Index [IX_Resposta_PerguntaID]    Script Date: 1/13/2016 9:06:19 AM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Resposta_PerguntaID] ON [quiz].[Resposta]
(
    [PerguntaID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Index [IX_Resposta_PerguntaProximaID]    Script Date: 1/13/2016 9:06:19 AM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Resposta_PerguntaProximaID] ON [quiz].[Resposta]
(
    [PerguntaProximaID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [quiz].[Resposta]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Resposta_Pergunta] FOREIGN KEY([PerguntaID])
REFERENCES [quiz].[Pergunta] ([PerguntaID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [quiz].[Resposta] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Resposta_Pergunta]
GO
ALTER TABLE [quiz].[Resposta]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Resposta_Pergunta_Proxima] FOREIGN KEY([PerguntaProximaID])
REFERENCES [quiz].[Pergunta] ([PerguntaID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [quiz].[Resposta] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Resposta_Pergunta_Proxima]
GO
```

Se preferir, a Tabela `Pergunta` pode ter uma coluna `ProximaPerguntaID` que servirá de valor default caso a coluna `ProximaPerguntaID` da tabela `Resposta` não for informado.